# How connectly import several variables from other file (Vue.JS)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, eslint

In `Vue.JS` application, I try to use `Vuex Store`. In `state.js` file I import some configurations from another custom file. In my case, it is `config.js`.

In the terminal I see such warning:

```
 warning  in ./src/store/state.js
"export 'colors' was not found in '@/../config.js'
"export 'config' was not found in '@/../config.js'
```

Inside browser console I see such error:

```
state.js?fcc2:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'theme' of undefined
    at eval (state.js?fcc2:15)
    at Module../src/store/state.js (app.js:3879)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:770)
    at fn (app.js:130)
    at eval (store.js?07a4:1)
    at Module../src/store/store.js (app.js:3891)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:770)
    at fn (app.js:130)
    at eval (main.js:19)
    at Module../src/main.js (app.js:3819)
```

**store.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import state from './state'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  strict: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
})
```

**state.js:**

```
import {
  config,
  colors
} from '@/../config.js'

const state = {
  theme: config.theme || 'light',
  themePrimaryColor: colors.primary
}

export default state
```

**config.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuesax from 'vuesax'

const colors = {
  primary: '#7367F0'
}

Vue.use(Vuesax, {
  theme: {
    colors
  }
})

const config = {
  theme: 'light'
}

export default config
```

Comment: You need to export `colors` from config.js - `export colors`

Comment: It seems to me that I can't use several exports in per module. `ESLint` raise syntax error. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Inside config.js remove `export default config` and replace it with `export {config, colors}` then everywhere it's referenced you need to either import everything aliased `import * as config from 'config.js` or import individual values like `import { colors } from 'config.js'`

Answer (score 0):

Just change your export to `export {colors, config}` in your config.js

You can then import it like this (you have it already implemented):

```
import {config, colors} from '@/../config.js'
```

Comment: I did as you advised. Unfortunately I see such error: `Syntax Error: SyntaxError: config.js: Only one default export allowed per module`. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Inside `config.js` file I add next code `export default {themeConfig, colors}`, but the problem is the same. I also tried to remove `colors`. In that case I see such error: `vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5100 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'install' of undefined`. What can you recommend?

Comment: You can't have multiple default exports.